# Getting custom tags from AWS instance browser function

Tags: python, batch-file, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm trying to get the "name" tag from the AWS instance via their internal browser method.  In my batch/script I have the following:

```
.\wget.exe -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id > c:\instance.id
```

Is there a way to get custom tags you create when you spin-up the instance?  I wanted to save off some information that I push when I create the instance via boto.  I can essentially match up the instance.id with the attribute that I create, in this case, a "name" tag.  But there doesn't seem to be a way to get that name tag from within the instance itself.

The above code represents an operation that I run within a batch to grab the instance.id, I want to do the same for a custom "tag".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot access the tags using the meta-data provided to the instance. What i recommend is using the user_data property of run_instances. Any data you save in the user_data property you can retrieve by downloading the file http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How does one insert data into that "user-data" property?  I'm my boto script, I have a simple "name" addition: `name="Proxy-"+str(x)+"-"+str(nenroll)+"-Enrollments"
  instance.add_tag("Name",name)`  I'm not clear on how I would do this for the user-data property?  Is there a link you can point me to that I can use?

Comment: Are you using the bototools or writing your own scripts with boto?

Comment: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ec2_tut.html. Look at the part where its running conn.run_instances. `conn.run_instances(
        '<ami-image-id>',
        key_name='myKey',
        user-data='<string of user data goes here',
        instance_type='c1.xlarge',
        security_groups=['your-security-group-here'])`

Comment: fantastic.. thanks, I'm writing boto scripts and I know exactly where that is and where is goes (what you wrote above). `reservation = myimage.run(instance_type='m1.large', key_name='will-aws'), user-data='proxy-#')` PERFECT!  Thanks man.

Comment: If my post was helpful could you mark the answer as complete?

Comment: sure, thanks for helping.  To complete, I just click the "check-mark" and set to green?